# androidTestCompile files under androidTest folder of a library

Tags: android, gradle

I have a library module and some application modules depending on that library module. Here is the question:

From an application module, how would you androidTestCompile files that are under the androidTest repository of the library module?

Comment: Did you find a proper solution?
I'm having a similar problem: Library with flavors, App module with android test code, which depends on the android test code of the library.

Comment: Not really. I moved to some other developments but maybe there are nice solutions now.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your app build.gradle

androidTestCompile  project(':YourLibarary')